# Why does the following regex match this text?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have the regex:  `(?ms)(?<attribute>\[.+?\]|public|private|\s)+?class`

and I have the text:

```
[attribute]
public int a;

[attribute C]
[attribute B]
public class Test{

}
```

**I would like to know why the regex that I posted matches:**

```
[attribute]
public int a;

[attribute C]
[attribute B]
public class
```

**I think it should match:**

```
[attribute C]
[attribute B]
public class
```

---

Correct me if I am wrong. I think the way that the regex is supposed to be read is:

> Find either an attribute ( [ some attribute ] ) or public key word or private keyword or space.

So first the regex engine should match [attribute], then the '\n' (new line), then the `public` keyword.  After these, the keyword `int` is not an option, so why does it match it?

Comment: I highly recommend RegexBuddy, in case you don't already have it. I'm not affiliated with the product in any way; I just love it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a dot which matches anything, including close square brackets, whitespace, and (in single-line mode) newlines:

```
\[.+?\]
```

You should use this instead:

```
\[[^\]]+\]
```

Explanation:

```
\[     Match a literal open square bracket.
[^\]]  Match any character except a close square bracket.
+      One or more.
\]     Match a literal close square bracket.
```

Comment: yeah but I am making it not greedy meaning that it will continue until it matches ']' I think... why is it matching `public int a;` I still confused lol. +1 for making it work

Comment: Greediness does not change whether a match succeeds or fails. It only changes the search order.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will accept your answer as soon as stack overflow lets me

Comment: As far as I have seen, `.` doesn't match newlines (unless you use the `dotall` option). What language has `.` matching `\n`? (The `|\s)` means it won't affect this regex.)

Comment: I use the option (?s) at the begining that makes the `.` match `\r` and `\n`   The other option that I have (?m) makes the regex multiline meaning that `^` will match the begining of a new line and `$` matches end of a line. In this case I am using both cases so I have (?sm) at the begining of my regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `Regex`:

```
((?<attribute>(?:public|private|\[[^\]]+\]))[\r\n\s]+)*class
```

and give group named `attribute`. your code can be like this:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(inputString, @"((?<attribute>(?:public|private|\[[^\]]+\]))[\r\n\s]+)*class"))
{
    var attributes = new List<string>();
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups["attribute"].Captures)
    {
        attributes.Add(capture.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but you don't given any explanation about the original problem in the OP's regex.